# 2.8 locking object from selection

Tags: selection-tools, outliner

I want to lock objects from getting selected, but not change their visibility.

2.8 removed the lock button from the outliner. How do you lock objects in 2.8?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Did you check the option in outline panel?

[image]

Comment: For anyone else who reads this and still can't get it to work, see the animation in the answer below.

Comment: Yeah this hardly answers the question, it "answers" it with another question.

Answer (score 72):

The option to make objects not selectable still exists. On the top of the outliner window look for a filter icon (looks like a funnel).
Click on it and you will have access to other restriction toggle switches for the objects in the outliner.

[image]

Comment: Now it's so obvious, thank you!

Comment: Works fine on Blender 2.9, just scale the outliner menu to the left and you will find it