# Can't select mesh

Tags: interface, selection-tools, outliner, select

I have this base body pony and i cant select it in object mode.
What do I do so I can adjust it?

if this cant be dun meby there is a way to get it animate?
i mage to grab all other stuff like main, tail, wings, eyes but all of that is mesh so i think i will be abol to put bones inside ones i convert it or what i need to do to do this thanks :-)

[image][image][image]

Comment: Hello :). Are you sure the object isn't just locked from selection?  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/144962/78972

Comment: omg it works thanks :-) wow i did not think to look there thanks

Comment: yes thanks for the help